# Create local account using Microsoft.Graph SDK in Azure AD B2C

Tags: c#, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to add local account to Azure AD B2C using the `Microsoft.Graph` SDK?

The Microsoft Graph API documentation requires that [this data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser) is sent (distinct members from that of work/school account).

I tried this:

```
User createdUser = graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = "TestUser",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
        Password = "Abcd@1234"
    },
    UserPrincipalName = "testuser@test.com",
    MailNickname = "testuser@test.com",
}).Result;
```

But it just returns an exception of `ServiceException: Code: InternalServerError Message: The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

There is [`Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) but is this not being deprecated? A lot of the "old" samples mention: *"It is recommended for new projects to use Microsoft.Graph SDK"*, or words to that effect, at the top of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently.. You can't.

See [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/173) and [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/91#issuecomment-322839828)

Comment: Here the user voice for the feature request https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34793269-support-azure-ad-b2c-local-account